# Using Lambda expression to compare User Id (MVC 5, Identity)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have stored the user profile in another table, called Agent. The Agent table does not contain any navigation property since i couldn't find a way to store user id in the Agents table( in the examples from msdn, even they didn't do it).

An Agent has many packages, and now i have a create packages view. I wanted to store the logged in Agent's ID to get stored in the Packages. So in the package controller in the Post Create actionResult, i'm doing something like this:

```
 var user = adb.Users.Where(p => p.Id == User.Identity.GetUserId()).Single();
        var agent = db.Agents.Where(p => p.ID == user.Agent.ID).Single();
```

(I have 2 datacontext, one from the application user, and one i got from datafirst EF, i tried merging them, but i got errors.)

I am getting errors.

> System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: that user.identity.getUserId() take it out and assign the id in a variable

Answer (score 0):

The [Enumerable.Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx) returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence. It throws [InvalidOperationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.100).aspx) , because the input sequence contains more than one element OR the input sequence is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Enumerable.Single, I would recommend using SingleOrDefault. This method returns null if there are no elements in the Enumerable rather than InvalidOperationException. You can then check for null value and take appropriate action if there is no entry in the Enumerable.

Ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in tables data (Users, Agents).
If you search by `Id`, I hope it's a key for tables, so I decided that you didn't add same records in one table, so we can remove variant that there are duplicates. If you use `User.Identity.GetUserId()` it's give background for decide that your user account already exist and the data in Users table is normal. `InvalidOperationException` in those places you can get if there are duplicates or data not exist. Variants with duplicates is left and I hope you use `ID` like key for table, so your problem is: You haven't any users in `Agent` table with `ID` which you get from `user.Agent.ID`. Two ways: wrong data in Agent or you get incorrect Id from `user.Agent.ID`(maybe problem in mapping). Try to create new User and new Agent for him and run your code. Are you sure that for all users should be an agent?

Comment: All Users can either be Agent or Customer. But the sole problem is that I have to save both agent and customer separately since the data is not the same. So the real problem for me i think is,  How can i Make the user ID key to become a foreign key and a primary key in Agent?